# Storytelling in a DOOM style game

Tags: first-person-shooter, storyboard

What if you have storytelling elements - nothing too complicated or convoluted, but you have a doom like game?

How can you convey the story through the medium?

I am saying specifically Doom like game, and not FPS, because for example, there will be no cutscenes

Answer (score 3):

Environmental storytelling.

Use the environment details of your games to tell the story. You can do that:

- Verbally: Through voice lines from enemies or NPCs.
- Textually: By having written information on the level geometry. This doesn't necessarily mean long texts for the player to read. A poster or direction sign can tell the player a lot about what goes on in the game world.
- Visually: By integrating story detail into the look of the game environment. Architecture and aesthetics can communicate a lot about where and when the game takes place. Clutter can communicate what currently goes on in the world. You can even design individual places in a way that tells a story. Like placing dead bodies in poses which clearly tell the player how those people died. Or at least inspire their fantasy to fill in the gaps.
- Tactile: By having the player do things, which then affect the game environment. Free hostages, blow up structures, raise flags, etc.

One game series which does that really well is *Half Life*. Another game studio that is really good at environmental storytelling is Bethesda (*Skyrim*, *Fallout*). If you own any of those games, then I recommend to install them again and pay a lot of attention to how those games show you stories without outright telling them to you.

Comment: I usually see "environmental storytelling" used to refer to things the player can passively observe — like your examples of architecture, dioramas suggestive of recent events, graffiti, etc. — but also things like encounters the player can walk in on, like two characters in the midst of arguing/fighting which tells you something about the conflicts/sides in this world. Stuff the player actively participates in, like mission objectives, collectible audio/text logs, I usually see classed as storytelling through gameplay / narrative design, rather than being labelled "environmental" specifically.